# cannot find symbol.inFocusDisplaying

Tags: android, kotlin, onesignal

```
D:\Android_officeworks\voiceonapp_1\app\src\main\java\com\voiceon\android\app\VoiceOnApplication.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable OSInFocusDisplayOption
  location: class OneSignal                 
D:\Android_officeworks\voiceonapp_1\app\src\main\java\com\voiceon\android\app\VoiceOnApplication.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                 ^
  symbol:   method startInit(VoiceOnApplication)
  location: class OneSignal

D:\Android_officeworks\voiceonapp_1\app\src\main\java\com\voiceon\android\app\VoiceOnApplication.java:178: error: cannot find symbol
        OneSignal.sendTag(key, value);
                 ^
  symbol:   method sendTag(String,String)
  location: class OneSignal
  
 OneSignal.startInit(this)                                  //initWithContext(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
 


     public void sendOneSignal(String key ,String value){
        OneSignal.sendTag(key, value);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files and the code where this error originates from?

Comment: If I recall correctly, OneSignal 5 has many breaking changes as compared to OneSignal 4 - you might've accidentally used v5 instead of v4, or you're referencing outdated documentation. I also don't see how the [tag:kotlin] tag is relevant here if the error appears to mention Java sources?